# Setting Currency in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsnumberformatter

I have a setting within my App to change currency.  I have since realised that this will cause problems due to different keypad locales where you could possible have a mismatch in the currency against what the keypad is e.g. euro selected in App, which uses comma as decimal separator and a locale keypad of the UK with a decimal separator.

Is the best approach to delete the setting I have and just set the currency to the locale of the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. The decimal separator is based on the user's locale, not the chosen currency. For example, say you have a user in a country that uses the comma for the decimal separator but they choose US dollars. Just because people in the US normally use the period as the decimal separator doesn't mean this user wants to change to using a foreign number format. They would enter the currency in US dollars but with a comma.

Comment: Thanks, was over thinking this I think!

Comment: Just remember that the decimal separator is not tied to the currency, but the locale.

Comment: My difficulty is trying to work out how to display the currency back to the user based on their selection.  I need to know what currency they have selected to work out where the symbol goes?

Comment: Use NSNumberFormatter in Currency mode. Set the chosen currency symbol for the formatter and let the formatter show the currency formatted properly for the user's locale. Again, don't over think this.

Comment: Yes thats what im doing currently.  But say my locale is UK and i've changed the currency to Euros, it is displaying as €xxx,xxx.xx due to my locale but should be xxx.xxx,xx€ due to the currency selected?

Comment: I think it is working fine. I think most people want to see the number formatted based on their locale.